Additivity of satellite functor
Let $T\colon \mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{B}$ be an additive functor between abelian categories and assume $\mathcal{B}$ has limits.  We define the first satellite functor $S_1T\colon \mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{B}$ by the following procedure.
For every $A\in \mathcal{A}$ let $\mathcal{P}_A$ denote the collection of all short exact sequences (s.e.s.) $$\varepsilon\colon \ \ \ 0\to M\overset{i_{\varepsilon}}{\to} P\overset{p_{\varepsilon}}{\to} A\to 0\,.$$ Assuming that each $\mathcal{P}_A$ is a set (or ignoring set theoretical issues) we obtain the inverse system in $\mathcal{B}$ $$\{\left(\operatorname{Ker} T(i_{\varepsilon})\right)_{\varepsilon\in\mathcal{P}_A},(\psi_{\varepsilon}^{\eta})_{\varepsilon\leq \eta}\}$$ where $(\mathcal{P}_A,\leq)$ is directed by defining $\varepsilon\leq \eta$ if there is a morphism of s.e.s. $(f,g,1_A)\colon \eta \to \varepsilon$, i.e., a commutative diagram

and $\psi_{\varepsilon}^{\eta}$ is the unique morphism such that the diagram below commutes:

With this information, the functor $S_1T\colon \mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}$ is defined by $S_1T(A)= \underset{\leftarrow}{\lim}\ \operatorname{Ker} T(i_{\varepsilon})$. And for a morphism $f\colon A\to B$ in $\mathcal{A}$, using the universal property of inverse limits after taking the pullback of each $\xi\in\mathcal{P}_B$ along $f$ and applying $T$ to the resultant diagram, we deduce $S_1T(f)$.
In this way, we obtain a functor which is supposedly additive. So far, all my attempts to prove this last assertion have been worthless. I'll appreciate your help.
References:
D.A. Buchsbaum, Satellites and Universal Functors.
B. Mitchell, Theory of Categories, Chapter VIII.

Informally speaking, your functor is defined as a limit, and limits preserve limits (in particular, finite products = sums).

@DenisT yes, this is the argument that convince myself that in fact the functor is additive. Nevertheless, I'm looking for full details in the given context.
